# Submit HTML form to external asp script

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am trying to write a html form to submit a few variables to an external asp file that creates a chat window.

The example that has been provided for me to use you can see by this [link](http://na.ntrsupport.com/nv/WebIntegration/Connectwise/contactform.aspx?account=41403&lang=us&banner=0&button=connect), but this involves a two step process.

In the example provided, the customer fills out the fields, clicks on "Submit" and is then taken to a separate page to click on a dynamically generated javascript link to launch the chat window.

I want do to this on a single page instead, but am having trouble finding a way to pass variables from my HTML form correctly to the external script

```
<script language='JavaScript' src='https://na.ntrsupport.com/nv/inquiero/web/an/ann4.asp?login=41403&lang=us&button=connect&cat=&cob=&oper=&skin=&urloffline=&urlbusy=&sur=&surpre=&bgcolor=&txtcolor=&ref2=/o1https://na.ntrsupport.com/nv/Webintegration/Connectwise/entrypoint.asp?p=1;email%40address.com;Description;Customers+Name;Company+Name&ref=Customers+Name&clientid=Company+Name'> </script>
```

In the code above I've entered generic text into the fields like "Company Name" and "email@address.com" to get that example link.

I've tried doing this a number of ways but none have resulted the desired result, such as using javascript direct to url with variables from the form, and url in the action part of the html form.

I don't have any control over how the script at na.ntrsupport.com works or receives the request so I have to get this working from my end.

Any help is going to be appreciated, and let me know if I've missed anything of importance.

My code so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Chat</title>
<script>
function launchChat()
{
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var company = document.getElementById('company').value;
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var description = document.getElementById('description').value;

  var url = "https://na.ntrsupport.com/nv/inquiero/web/an/ann4.asp?login=41403&lang=us&button=connect&cat=&cob=&oper=&skin=&urloffline=&urlbusy=&sur=&surpre=&bgcolor=&txtcolor=&ref2=/o1https://na.ntrsupport.com/nv/Webintegration/Connectwise/entrypoint.asp?p=1;" + email + ";" + description + ";" + name + ";" + company + "&ref=" + name + "&clientid=" + company;

window.location(url);
return false;
}
</script>
<style>
div{
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-100px; /* Negative half the width*/
    margin-top:-100px; /* Negative half the height */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<form onsubmit="return launchChat();">
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan=2>
Put Banner here
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Name:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id=="name" name="name" required>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Company:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="company" name="company" required>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Email:
</td>
<td>
<input type="email" id=name="email" name="email" required>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Description:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="description" name="description" required>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2>

<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Start Chatting"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you having trouble building an URL like that?

Comment: I can build the URL using javascript and getting the variables from the fields, but how do I then call on the external script with the built url?

Comment: I'm 99% sure what's wrong, but before I give you an answer, would you mind showing me your form and the code related to it?

Comment: Hi Shomz, I modified the orignal question to include the source code

Comment: Hi, I'll give you an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so you made it a bit too complicated there.

First thing: you need to use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) (this is the key!) on those variables you're concatting to the string because chances are some of them will have characters not allowed in the url.

Second: using GET method on the form will automatically build urls like that. For example:

```
<form action="a.html" method="GET">
    <input name="var1" value="value1" />
    <input name="var1" value="value1" />
</form>
```

will automatically build the link that looks like: `a.html?var1=value1&var2=value2`, which is a part of what you need and can make your life easier. I know you basically need to build two of those (the main url, which I'm not sure will remain hardcoded; and the `ref2` part).

---

Another thing:

```
window.location(url);
```

should be:

```
window.location = url;
```

Comment: The "https://na.ntrsupport.com/nv/inquiero/web/an/ann4.asp?login=41403&lang=us&button=connect&cat=&cob=&oper=&skin=&urloffline=&urlbusy=&sur=&surpre=&bgcolor=&txtcolor=&ref2=/o1https://na.ntrsupport.com/nv/Webintegration/Connectwise/entrypoint.asp?p=1;" part will remain hardcoded, I just tried putting this in the action tag of the form but on submission it seems to truncate everything after ann4.asp?

Comment: That's weird, it could be related to the window.location (see my updated answer), but I don't understand why after ann3.asp... Tell me if it works now. You can output the url to the console (or alert it) instead of changing the location to see if it's getting built properly.

Comment: Oh hang on im getting confused here, should I be building the link in the launchChat() function or using the action in the form tag?

Comment: Whatever you decide, I suggested the form because it does it automatically and it might a better solution in the long run. But, if you plan to change only those few variables in a hardcoded link, you should probably stick to your method. But fix the window.location and encodeURIComponent; and always check your console for errors (that's why suggested not doing the actual redirection until you fix everything in your code).